# cannot run junit5 under eclipse (2020-06 (4.16.0))

Tags: eclipse, junit5

I can run a junit5 test fine under command line or run as Gradle Test in eclipse; but run it as junit in eclipse it simply failed:

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/junit/platform/commons/PreconditionViolationException
> at
> org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit5.runner.JUnit5TestLoader.createUnfilteredTest(JUnit5TestLoader.java:75)

I see this error in the older eclipse and in the new new eclipse 2020-06 (4.16.0).  What am I missing?

Comment: There are many things that can cause this. Please show a [minimal example to reproduce this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse 2020-06 is using junit jupiter engine v5.6. Your application most likely is using the lower version. Try to change your app dependency to the latest junit jupiter version.